# How to find the difference between two columns in Django model and print result for each row in view

Tags: python, django-models

```
class Daily(models.Model):
  rpt_date = models.DateField('Report Date', primary_key=True) 
  total_d_sors = models.IntegerField() 
  loaded_d_sors = models.IntegerField()
  #diff_d_count
  d_sors_missed_eod = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  total_m_sors = models.IntegerField() #monthly
  loaded_m_sors = models.IntegerField() #monthly
  m_sors_missed_eod = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

I have the above class in my models.py but when I display it through a view I need to have an additional column which will have the difference between two existing columns (total_d_sors and missed_d_sors) i.e., diff_d_count=(total_d_sors - missed_d_sors)... can someone help?
I'm seeing examples with cursor implementation; is there any other way?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: `def index(request):
  latest_list = Daily.objects.extra(select = {'diff':'select total_d_sors-loaded_d_sors from reports_Daily\
                '},).order_by('-rpt_date')[:14]
  return render_to_response('reports/index.html',{'latest_list':latest_list,})`                                    The above view when printed in html prints the same difference obtained for the first row for all the rows.. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: the `select` and `from reports_Daily` shouldn't be necessary. Try `...(select = {'diff': 'total_d_sors - loaded_d_sors'})...`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you add a property on the model and calculate it on the fly as you're displaying it in your template?

```
class Daily(models.Model):

  @property
  def diff_d_count(self):
    return self.total_d_sors - self.missed_d_sors
```

Then you can access it in your template or wherever via `obj.diff_d_count`.

Answer (score 2):

To find difference between 2 columns you can use,

**1.** [**annotate**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate)

**2.** [**F expression**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

Your query would be,

```
Daily.objects.annotate(diff=F('total_d_sors')-F('missed_d_sors'))
```

Sample working code with template,

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.template import Context, Template
context = Context({"daily_objects": Daily.objects.annotate(diff=F('total_d_sors')-F('missed_d_sors'))})
template = Template("{% for i in daily_objects %} {{i.id}} || {{i.diff}}. {% endfor %}")
template.render(context)
```